# Is there such a formula as IF/AND/OR in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm working on this spreadsheet, field B10.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wC-y0T9QeF6MZALavljzqVLJTfadSHmGt0yOFYgIMnE/edit?usp=sharing

I'd like to apply this formula, but I'm not sure how:

```
IF B10=TRUE AND B5=TRUE, THEN C10xG6
BUT 
IF B10=TRUE AND B5=FALSE, THEN C10*F6.
IF B10=FALSE, " ".
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this formula is more understandable and adherent to the request for a beginner:

```
=ifs(
and(B10=TRUE , B5=TRUE) , C10*G6,
and(B10=TRUE ,B5=FALSE) , C10*F6,
B10=FALSE, ""
)
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as already shown, two nested [**IF() functions**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en#null) solve your problem (See the **Nested_Outcome** formula in the [**Examples section**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en#null:%7E:text=first%20true%20condition.-,Examples,-Specifies%20a%20logical))

I want to show another way of calculating for combined conditions, without the `IF()` function.

Let's present all combinations of your conditions in the form of a table:

[image: First Table]

*(I wrote "Something else" to show that for the combination of **B10=FALSE AND B5=TRUE** some other option is possible, and not just a space, as in your case)*

Considering that FALSE is equal to 0 and TRUE is equal to 1 (at least for Google Spreadsheets this is the case), let's rewrite this table in a general form:

[image: Second Table]

You can get the option number from the B5 and B10 values with a very simple formula: `=B10*2+B5+1`

Now use the [**CHOOSE() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093371?hl=en#null): specify this expression as the first parameter ***index***, and then list all four possible options separated by commas -

`=CHOOSE(B10*2+B5+1,"","",C10*F6,C10*G6)`

Of course, for two conditions, the benefit from this approach is not very noticeable. But the same principle can be used for both three and four conditions - it is enough to multiply the value of each condition by the next power of 2:

`=CHOOSE(4th_condition*8+3rd_condition*4+2nd_condition*2+1st_condition+1,...)`

Yes, the formula will be quite long. But in any case, it will be shorter and clearer than eight nested IF() functions.

Comment: @ JohnSUN change your formula in `=CHOOSE(B10*2+B5+1,"","",C10*F6,C10*G6)`

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo code example:

```
IF B10=TRUE AND B5=TRUE, THEN C10xG6 
BUT 
IF B10=TRUE AND B5=FALSE, THEN C10*F6.
IF B10=FALSE, " ".
```

How to accomplish in google sheets:

```
=if(n(B10)=n(whatthefoxsay())," ",if(B5,multiply(C10,G6),multiply(C10,F6)))
```

Comment: small mistake ... change this part
`= if (n (B11)`
with this
`= if (n (B10)`

Comment: @Daniele changed it to B10

Answer (score 1):

> =IF(B10=TRUE,IF(B5=TRUE,C10*G6,C10*F6),"")

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can remove the two ‘=TRUE’ as they are redundant.

Comment: Hello! I know,  I preferred it to remain more clear and direct from the original logic suggested ;)